# Connecting a WiiMote to an android device

Tags: android, bluetooth, uuid, wiimote

Does anyone know the UUID to connect an android 2.2 device to a WiiMote?  The wiimote will not pair, as the wiimote does not require a PIN #.

Comment: I found this answer useful: [Is it possible for an android device to read information from the wii controller and nunchuck?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9669315/383414) (quoted below with thanks to @Ben Mordue) > Have a look at this open source project:
> http://code.google.com/p/android-bluez-ime/ I have not looked at the source code yet, but have installed the APK file on Galaxy Nexus and it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, you can only connect a Wiimote to a non-Wii device if you use a bluetooth stack/program that allows you to skip the PIN. This is possible a couple of different ways on laptops and such, but Android 2.2 requires the PIN for the first pairing.

However, depending on what kind of phone you have, you can try the [WiimoteController](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=672884) app. It doesn't connect on HTC devices that are running the Sense UI, but if you have a Nexus One or you're running some kind of custom vanilla Android ROM on your phone, it should work.

Comment: Well the guy at WiimoteController can do it, so I would like to learn how to do it also.

Answer (score 3):

Apologies for answer an old question, but to pair the Wiimote using legacy pairing, you reverse the bytes of the device address and use that as the pin.

Comment: Can you give more detail on "Reverse the bytes" Looking elsewhere it seems like you're supposed to convert the MAC address to decimal and put it in last to first with no spaces but that doesn't work for me.

Comment: http://wiibrew.org/wiki/Wiimote#Bluetooth_Pairing explains what @Arkamis is talking about, but I don't think that's very helpful here. The native bluetooth pairing only allows ascii characters; this requires other values (looks like it will always include an 0x00, for example, which can't be input from a standard keyboard).

Comment: funny that I said "an 0x00" ... is that proper?