# Is it possible for an android device to read information from the wii controller and nunchuck?

Tags: android

I am new to android development and have a few questions.

1: Can I make android devices read and use the information from the Wii controller and nunchuck?
   The functions I need from the Wii controller is movement (imagine a game where you slash in the air and similar movements happen in the game), the joystick on the nunchuk and buttons on both controllers.

2: If this is possible where can I learn to implement this in my application/game?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at this open source project: http://code.google.com/p/android-bluez-ime/

Answer (score 4):

1. Yes, the wii controllers are all bluetooth. You can pair your android device with any bluetooth device. There are actually apps already in existence that do this (android-wiimote) available.
2. If you look through the source code of [imame4all](http://code.google.com/p/imame4all/), they actually demonstrate this support.

In particular, [this](http://code.google.com/p/imame4all/source/search?q=wii&origq=wii&btnG=Search+Trunk) should start you off.